# In Ruby on Rails how to apply active state to navigation depending on the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a nav partial that's rendering on the application that every other page is inheriting. Then in the application it's looking for body content to render. The navigation links are something like:

```
<ul class="ul-class">
 <li class="li-class"><a href="1">One</a></li>
 <li class="li-class"><a href="2">Two</a></li>
 <li class="li-class"><a href="3">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
I **cannot** adjust the li or a tag as they're being pulled down from our CMS. The only thing I can affect is added a class to the ul or the li.

What I'm trying to do is if a person clicks and goes to page Two that Two is then marked active with a border on the bottom. CSS like this:

```
.nav-active {
border-bottom: 5px solid #d9d9d9;
padding-bottom: 21px;
}
```

I know I have some jQuery code that will do this (minus some border issues) but I'm trying to do it the Rails way.

For reference the application file has:

```
<body>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/nav' %>
  <%= content_for?(:body) ? yield(:body) : yield %>
  <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
</body>
```

Then in two file I have:

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles/two' %>
<% end %>
<%= content_for :body do%>
  <h2>Words going here</h2>
<% end %>
```

Navigation is present but I'd like for Two to be active. I've tried something like this and it did nothing:

```
<%= if current_page?('two') then '.nav-active%>
  <%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles/two' %>
  <% end %>
   <%= content_for :body do%>
    <h2>Words going here</h2>
  <% end %>
```

Is there a better/actual way to apply CSS to the current page in Rails?

EDIT: Also tried the following:

```
<%= 'nav-active' if current_page?('/two') %>
```

This kind of worked but not really. It's not really applying a class but the word nav-active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_class?(test_path)
    return 'nav-active' if request.path == test_path
    ''
  end

end
```

And use it in your erb template:

```
<li class="li-class <%= current_class?('/two') %> "><a href="2">Two</a></li>
```

A more rails way would be to use the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) helper:

```
<%= link_to "Two", '/2', class: current_class?('/two')  %>
```

---

There is also an [active_link_to gem](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to) which wraps `link_to` helper, with the facility to inject configurable conditions when the link would be considered active.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the li beyond giving it a class based on our CMS.

Comment: You can't use a helper to get that class ?

Comment: What cms is this ?

Comment: Using twice baked. https://rubygems.org/gems/tb_blog. The ul/li is actually written in my view as <%= sp_list_menu(id: 'nav-list', class: 'ul-class' name: 'navlist', max_depth: 2)%>. Name is the menu that's being pulled down. In the CMS I added a class to the menu items (li's).